# Wordpress - Get http response code in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I want to get the server http response code in the wordpress functions.php theme file.

I guess this is because the server has not send it's response yet, this below is not working (on a page that doesn't exist) :

```
$found = is_404();
var_dump($found);
// returns false
var_dump(http_response_code());
// returns 200
```

What would be the right way to get this status number here ?

Comment: Can you give a higher level reason for what you are attempting? For instance, do you want to perform your own custom logic when a 404 happens, like perform additional API or database requests?

Comment: I use require_once() in my functions.php to include code for some urls. But if the page doesn't exist, the server fires an 500 error on this particular code instead of a 404 error. The idea is to include those files only if the URL exists.

Comment: And you want to do this always? Only when WordPress can't handle it (and for argument's sake let's call that a 404)? When there's a 301? 418?

Comment: I edited my previous answer. I want to include those files only when the URL exists.

Comment: `is_404()` would be checking if the WordPress URL the user requested, was a 404, or not. That has nothing whatsoever to do with any external URLs, that you request in your server-side code. _“I want to include those files only when the URL exists”_ - then you need to make at least a HEAD request. And if you make those all the time, only to have them followed by a second GET request that then actually fetches the data, it might make more sense to just make the GET request directly (and deal with potential errors after.)

Comment: Writing code directly in functions.php is probably a really bad idea for what you are trying to do, you most definitely want to do this in a hook at least, which then can be in functions.php

Comment: _“I use require_once() in my functions.php to include code for some urls. But if the page doesn't exist, the server fires an 500 error”_ - that’s because `require` _is supposed to_ let the script die, if it can’t fetch the requested file or URL. Maybe you simply want to use `include_once` instead then …?

Comment: I did not explained myself the right way. The files I need to include are on the same server in the theme folder too, they are always here. This is not the point. the 404 I am trying to detect is on the requested page. Actually the right way to say it would be "I want to include a file (or doing something else) in functions.php file if the requested URL is found by the server".

Comment: Do the files that you want to include output something, hijack the stream, or just do background work? If they output something, I would do this in header.php or footer.php, whichever is appropriate, with an `is_404()` check. If they hijack the steam, I would do this in the `template_include` hook which is actually intended for this. If they do background work, I think I would use `template_include` once again.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress we can get the http response code of any webpage using WordPress functions itself like below.

```
<?php
    $url = "https://www.example.com";
    $response = wp_remote_get($url);
    if( !is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);    
        echo $response_code;
    }
?>
```